# Editing JSTL values with the click of a button

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, jstl

The following is the JSP page created to show records of messages and comments in a social networking app.

[image: message along with like and flag values and their buttons]

My question is that with the click of the like and flag buttons the values for like and flag for the respective comment/message should increment automatically. Basically it is clicking the button and updating JSTL record.

I don't know how to go about... any pointers on how to achieve this???

Comment: You need to use ajax for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to reload the entire page on click, use Java script to send the AJAX request to server, update the count in your backend, update the HTML back using AJAX call back function.For example: you can refer http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp.  Framework's like Jquery/AngularJS have simpler support for this.